# es6 variable into string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on a React ES6 application.

Is it possible to declare a variable which will be taken as a variable name, like below with refInput ?

```
renderInput(inputName) {
    const refInput = `${inputName}Input`;

    return (
        <Input
            ref={(node) => {
                this.refInput = node;
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I am really struggling with this

Comment: You can construct object property names dynamically, but not variable names.

Comment: Are you looking for `this[refInput] = node;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add properties into an object dynamically,you can use property bracket accessor notation [`[string_name]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)  on an object.or you can [ref element by attribute with string name](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

```
renderInput(inputName) {
  const refInput = `${inputName}Input`;

  return (
    <Input
        ref={(node) => {
            this[refInput] = node;
        }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `[]` is not an operator.

Comment: it tagged as an operator in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: MDN is not the source of truth, the spec is. MDN is great in general, but it has some minor inaccuracies.

Comment: could you tell me what the name of []? and I will edit the answer.thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That is now working like expected

Comment: The page you linked to actually uses an appropriate term: *property accessor*. And there are two of accessing properties: Using *dot notation* (`foo.bar`) or *bracket notation* (`foo[bar]`).

Comment: @Franck Not at all

Comment: @Franck: Please also refer to duplicate question to get more familiar with the proper terminology.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks!!

Comment: @FelixKling - I searched and did not found it as I am pretty new I guess I did not search with the right terms. Anyways thanks ! It seems really basic and yet it is the first time I see it.

Comment: @Franck: Right, it's impossible to find something if you don't know what to search for :) That's why I suggested to look at the terminology used on the duplicate.

Comment: @FelixKling up!!!the main problem is how to describe the problem correctly.I agree too.